# Trying to use static resource in visualforce page controller test class

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I have a visualforce page controller class which has a soql in the beginning

```
select <fields> from <custom_object_A> where appnum = <fetched_from_vf_page_parameter>;
```

The controller class has lot of calculations after that soql. I am trying to create a test class. Since i want the test class to pass through various scenarios of the controller class, i will have to pass a lot of records to the custom_object_A.

I am wondering if i can use a csv file with records from the custom_object_A and upload as a static resource? I am not sure if i will have to insert the data in my custom_object_A in the test class or i can use the the static resource and loop through the rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed. The functionality you're looking for is [`Test.loadData()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm). From that documentation, the steps to use it are

> 1. Add the data in a .csv file.
> 2. Create a static resource for this file.
> 3. Call `Test.loadData` within your test method and passing it the sObject type token and the static resource name.

You can call `Test.loadData()` in your `@isTest` test method or your `@testSetup` initialization method. You won't need to write any inserts or touch the CSV content yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following on the case object and it worked. Thank you David!

**Controller Class**

public class caseextn {
public case case1{get;set;}
public  caseextn (ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        string casenum= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('casenum');
        system.debug('casenum' + casenum);
        try{
              case1 = [Select  ownerid,id from case where casenumber = :casenum];
            System.debug('case values'+ case1 );

```
    }
    catch(exception e){
        system.debug('In ERROR No exception calculator record found for this application.');
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'No exception calculator record found for the application: ' + casenum+'.')); 
    }
} //constructor end
```

}

**VFPage**

**Test Class**

@isTest
private class casetest {

private static testMethod void test() {
     List caselst = Test.loadData(case.sObjectType, 'case');
     system.debug('caselst '+caselst);
     List caselst1 = (list)caselst;

```
 Test.StartTest();  

for (case case1 : caselst1){
PageReference pageRef = Page.caseitemsvfpage; // Add your VF page Name here
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
system.debug('pageRef1 '+pageRef);
pageRef.getParameters().put('casenum', String.valueOf(case1.caseNumber)); 
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(case1);
caseextn ece = new caseextn(sc);   
system.debug('pageRef3 '+pageRef);  
 }
```

Test.StopTest();
   }
}

**case static resource file:**

"CaseNumber","Subject","Status","Priority"
"00001002","Seeking guidance on electrical wiring installation for GC5060","New","Low"
"00001016","Maintenance guidelines for generator unclear","New","Low"
"00001024","Design issue with mechanical rotor","New","Low"